# Связь двух баз данных

Tags: 1с

Ясного неба!

Есть у меня две базы с различными конфигурациями. Я настроил автоматический экспорт некоторых данных (пусть это будут счета) между ними. Но этот экспорт длится минут 40, так как из одной базы выгружаются данные, создается огромный промежуточный xml файл, в котором они складируются, а потом это всю всасывается во вторую базу.

Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в возможностях системы 1С, поэтому у меня возник этот вопрос: можно ли каким-то образом, стандартными средствами, "связать" две базы между собой, чтобы при внесении изменений (допустим в документе "Счет") в одной из них, во второй базе они так же происходили?

Да, я могу изобрести велосипед - заставить одну базу писать своеобразный лог, а вторую каждые 5 минут его проверять, и выполнять аналогичные действия. Но может все намного проще? Ведь огромные предприятия, которые могут пользоваться сразу несколькими системами (управление персоналом, предприятие и бухгалтерия, например), как-то устанавливают их связь между собой? Или так никто (кроме нас) не делает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Проф. разработка в 1С8.2, изд.2 / Том 2 / Глава 19. Обмен данными](http://langslab.com/ebooks/prof-dev2/tome2/pr-dev-t2-ch19)

Answer (score 0):

В 1с есть специальные объекты для отслеживания изменений - [планы обмена](http://programmist1s.ru/planyi-obmena-1s/).

Если вы хотите настроить "онлайн" обмен -  то это достаточно проблематично. Хотя можно попробывать копнуть в строну [внешних источников данных](http://programmist1s.ru/vneshnie-istochniki-dannyih-1s/) и подключатся к таблице напрямую.