# 1C и приложения андроид

Tags: java, 1с

Автосалон заказал приложения для телефонов и хотят интегрировать свою базу, которая стоит на 1С. 
Приложения будет писать на джаве и скорее всего будет каким-то просто RESTful сервисом на спринге. 
Вопрос: можно ли вообще сконфигурировать гибернейт и спринг так, чтобы подключить продакшн к их базе 1С? Чтобы приложения могло использовать их базу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, придётся действовать через выгрузку номенклатуры (справочников, прайсов) из 1С в некоторое промежуточное хранилище с какой-то периодичностью.

С выгруженными прайсами (XML или CSV таблицы, например) уже работать через java-адаптер (можно в MongoDB на сервере приложения загружать документы для каждой позиции, там же их и обновлять).

Ну а с MongoDB уже пусть работает spring со своим чудесным драйвером.

Дальше - дело за REST API - как приложение будет работать с сервисом.

Обработку заказов нужно подвесить на имеющиеся бизнес-процессы (связать с имеющимся сайтом-магазином через сервис, например).

Comment: а как такая структура парсинга базы отобразится на перформенсе?

Comment: В общем-то не сильно заметно для пользователя.
1. Мы лишь раз в сутки (например в 4:00) или раз в месяц (в зависимости от требований бизнес процессов и обновляемости ассортимента) выгружаем номенклатуру в XML или таблицу, после чего обновляем состояние записей в MongoDB (или иной БД).
2. Сервис не работает напрямую с 1С БД заказчика (не тормозит работу других сервисов в "продающее время").
3. Сервис работает с "быстрой" БД (Монго или не нагруженная другими запросами локальная БД на машине с сервисом).
4. Приложение работает с сервисом и не страдает в плане производительности.

Comment: Узкие места: 1. Выгрузка номенклатуры в промежутоную БД. 2. Операции с веб-магазином (если он есть).

Вопрос: у компании есть веб-магазин на 1C или се сидят "на телефоне" и руками заказы в 1С оформляют?

Comment: Есть вариант (http://infostart.ru/public/359102/) пошаманить и сдружить 1С с Hibernate, но тогда возникают риски влияния производительности 1С на сервис. (А для хорошего потока заказов - service first, как-никак). Так что, лучше лишний раз сообщить клиенту, что товар скоро будет, чем упустить клиента из-за проблем с производительностью приложения.

Comment: Вот тут кстати обсуждался вопрос ро обмен данными: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/215894/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85?rq=1

Вот на что ссылаются в главном ответе: http://v8.1c.ru/metod/books/book.jsp?id=401